# mysql group by column error when alias specified

Tags: php, mysql

Following mysql query gives an error: `'email.id' isn't in GROUP BY, 1055`

```
SELECT contact_a.id as contact_id,
  contact_a.sort_name  as `sort_name`,
  contact_a.display_name  as `display_name`,
  phone.id as phone_id,
  phone.phone_type_id as phone_type_id,
  phone.phone as `phone`,
  email.id as `email_id`,
  email.email as `email`,

FROM contact_table contact_a
  LEFT JOIN email ON (contact_a.id = email.contact_id)
  LEFT JOIN phone ON (contact_a.id = phone.contact_id)

 GROUP BY contact_a.id,
  `sort_name`,
  `display_name`,
  `phone_id`,
  `phone_type_id`,
  `phone`,
  `email_id`,
  `email`";
```

eventhough I've specified the alias of `email.id` in `GROUP BY`.

If I replace the alias `email_id` in GROUP BY with `email.id`, it works.

But why can't I use the alias in GROUP BY and how can it work for other alias like `phone_id`, `phone_type_id`, `email` etc ?

Comment: Can you check if you have an actual email_id field in any of the tables referenced by the from clause? Moreover, I just do not see the point of your query. What's the point on doing a group by on all fields in the select list and +1 more?

Comment: `email` table has a column `id` in it. I've ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode enabled. So `email.id` is present

Comment: This is not what I have asked. I do understand that there is an email.id column. But is there in any of the tables referenced by the from clause an email_id column?

Comment: can you please post an answer? I still don't understand :(. If `email.id (which works)` is present in `from` referenced tables, how `email_id` cannot be there ?

Comment: I cannot post an answer, until you answer my above question. Is there a column named email_id in any of the above tables? Yes or no?

Comment: What is your MySQL server version?

Comment: What @Shadow said is, is there a column named `email_id ` in your table `contact_table` or `email` or `phone`.

Comment: No, if you're talking about `email_id` as a column in `contact_table` or `email` or `phone` table, they are not present in any of them

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone Server version: 5.5.37

Comment: @Shadow Yes, I get it, actually it was a long query, I've posted a smaller one for convenience considering they were just additional part. I do understand now, From clause also have two another tables and they have `email_id` as a column which can't be grouped by. Thanks!

Comment: I'll post it as an answer, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since mysql extends the mysql standard and allows you to use column aliases in the group by clause, the only think you need to pay attention to is not to use the same alias as an existing field name in any of the tables referenced in the from clause.

In case you use the same alias as an existing field, then mysql will interpret the group by clause as if it refferred to the existing field, not to the aliased one. This causes the above error message.